# How to add data to associative table in asp.net core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am new to asp.net core. I am building a web application for book management. I have a table called Author and books. Being a many to many relationships I made an associative entity that consists of the bookId and authorId. When I try to create I am able to create author and book. I successfully added the author and book to the database. 
My author class looks like this

```
 public class Author
{   
   private int _ID

    private string _Name;

    public string ID {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }

    public string Name {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
    }
```

My book class is

```
    public class Author
      {   
   private int _ID

    private string _Name;
    private string _Title;

    public string ID {
        get { return _ID; }
        set { _ID = value; }
}
        public string Title {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }
```

}

```
    public string Name {
        get { return _Name; }
        set { _Name = value; }

    }
```

I have a data access called db.cs to help to create the book and author in database.

```
    public static int AddAuthor(Author A)
    {
        int renum = -1;
        SqlConnection conn = null;

            conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("sproc_AuthorAdd", conn);
            comm.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", A.Name);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Title", a.Title);

            SqlParameter output = new SqlParameter();
            output.ParameterName = "@AuthorID";

            output.DbType = System.Data.DbType.Int32;
            output.Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output;
            comm.Parameters.Add(output);

            int affect = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
            renum = affect;
            c.ID = (int)output.Value;
```

I have done the same for books as well. I want to fill out the association table as well when the user filled out a book and author using their ID. I tried to do various things like using a cookie to pass data. But I cannot store data. Any kind of help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure I understand your last code snippet, but if you're having issues managing your many-to-many relationship between Books and Authors, have you considered just using [Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/)?

Instead of writing a bunch of code that accesses your database, you just create models of your tables (similar to the classes you have defined above), and it handles the many-to-many relationship for you. The code to query for Authors and/or Books could then look as simple as:

```cs
using (var db = new dbContext())
{
    var books = db.Books
        .Where(b => b.ID > 1234)
        .OrderBy(b => b.Title)
        .ToList();
}
```

And creating a new Book or Author would be similarly simple:

```cs
using (var db = new dbContext())
{
    var book = new Book { ID = 1234, Title = "Some Title", Name = "Some Name" };
    db.Books.Add(book);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

You might have to reimplement a bunch of things to take advantage of Entity Framework Core in your app, but it sounds like it would save you time in the long run.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I am trying not to use the entity framework. I am trying to do using plain MVC.